# Multi-tenant rails app with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, searchkick, apartment-gem

Some information about my app:

- Rails
- Implements multi-tenancy with using apartment gem
- Uses Elasticsearch through searchkick gem

Multi-tenancy will mean that there will be overlapping IDs for the same model.

First thing that came to my mind was to use searchkick's `index_prefix`, by setting `index_prefix` to the different tenant's name. But I realized that won't work because the value of `index_prefix` is set when the app starts. And the same value will remain throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a reply from the creator of searchkick that is is not possible.

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/268#issuecomment-53672954

Now I might look for some monkey patching alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

What we are doing is to send searchkick an index_name like this

```
searchkick autocomplete: ["some_fields_for_auto_complete"],
             index_name: -> { [Apartment::Tenant.current, model_name.plural, Rails.env].join('_') }
```

This will create different searchkick indexes for different tenants and works well during querying. Although be careful to reindex the model for all tenants when you have to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like Searchkick has added multi tenant support as of 2017-01-16 . Check it out at https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multi-tenancy .